# Как почистить cache у гита?

Tags: git

Как почистить `cache` у `git`'a ?

Comment: https://devconnected.com/how-to-clear-git-cache/

Comment: git rm --cached
использование: git rm [<опции>] [--] <файл>…

    -n, --dry-run         пробный запуск
    -q, --quiet           не выводить список удаленных файлов
    --cached              удалить только из индекса
    -f, --force           пропустить проверку актуальности
    -r                    разрешить рекурсивное удаление
    --ignore-unmatch      выход с нулевым кодом возврата, даже если ничего не найдено

Answer (score 0):

`git rm --cached` использование: `git rm [<опции>] [--] <файл>… -n`, `--dry-run` пробный запуск `-q`, `--quiet` не выводить список удаленных файлов --cached удалить только из индекса `-f`, `--force` пропустить проверку актуальности -r разрешить рекурсивное удаление `--ignore-unmatch` выход с нулевым кодом возврата, даже если ничего не найдено